# Replace column with values not equal to multiple values

Tags: sql, case-when, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If a value in a column is not either A or B, then replace that value with "NO".

```
dataset

ColA     ColB
   A        L
NULL        P
   B        M
   C        G
```

Expected Output:

```
ColA     ColB
   A        L
  NO        P
   B        M
  NO        G
```

I tried this but no luck:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN ColA NOT IN(A,B) REPLACE (ColA, ColA, 'NO') 
ELSE ColA 
END ColA 
FROM dataset;
```

It returns a column of all "NO".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, should not compile, so I guess it is not the actual code. 
(1) It is missing `THEN` after `WHEN`.
(2) The values `A` and `B` should be enclosed in single quotes, otherwise they would be recognized as column names. 
So it should be written as:

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE 
    WHEN ColA NOT IN('A','B') THEN REPLACE(ColA, ColA, 'NO') 
    ELSE ColA 
  END NewColA 
FROM dataset;
```

This would produce the desired results unless there is a `NULL` value in `ColA`. 
In case of `NULL`, `ColA NOT IN('A','B')` would evaluate to `NULL` and no replacement would take place. 
You can write the statement using **Snowflake**'s [`IFF()`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/iff.html) function like this:

```
SELECT *, IFF(ColA IN ('A', 'B'), ColA, 'NO') NewColA
FROM dataset;
```

In case `ColA IN ('A', 'B')` evaluates to `NULL` then the `FALSE` part of `IFF()` is returned which is `'NO'`

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` is not needed just use `case` expression :

```
select d.*, (case when cola in ('a', 'b')
                  then cola else 'NO'
             end)
from dataset d;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ColA NOT LIKE 'A' OR 'B' THEN 'NO' ELSE ColA END AS 'ColA'
,ColB
FROM Dataset;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this...

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, ColN,
       CASE
         WHEN ColA = 'A' OR ColA = 'B' THEN ColA
         ELSE NULL
       END AS ColA
FROM   dataset
```

Answer (score -1):

To be on the safe side you most likely also need to add a `IS NULL` check also. 
i believe SQL standards defined `NOT IN()` should not work with NULL values..

As `ColA  NOT IN('A','B')` is the same as writting `ColA <> 'A' OR ColB <> 'B'` and  `SELECT 'A' <> NULL` should never not be true.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  (
    CASE
      WHEN ColA NOT IN('A','B') OR ColA IS NULL
      THEN 'NO'
      ELSE ColA
    END
  ) AS ColA
  , ColB
FROM 
 dataset
```